# How to add opacity in spline chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to add opacity in spline chart for Highcharts 7.0.1.

As per the  [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.opacity), I can see the **opacity** option is only available in Highcharts 7.1.0 and above. Is there any way to add the option for the version 7.0.1

```
plotOptions: {
      column: {
        
      },
       spline: {
         opacity: '0.4'
       }
    },
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/ma4j6dkq/2/)

Comment: Is it an option for you to set the `visible` [property](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.visible) to false instead of changing the opacity to zero?

Comment: @UfguFugullu visible option is to Set the initial visibility of the series. In my case, I want the opacity option Opacity is the degree to which content behind an element is hidden, and is the opposite of transparency

Comment: @UfguFugullu I don't want to hide the series. I just want to decrease the opacity of the line chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the series color in rgba format:

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        color: 'rgba(55,55,55,0.5)'
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fvu9ka4p/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.color

Comment: You are awesome.